# Bulk update the product attributes using Magento 2 import tool - Product SKU / Custom Product Attribute

Tags: magento-2.1.7

Bulk update the product attributes using Magento import tool: 

The Required fields(CSV) are: 

1) Product SKU (required)
2) Custom Product Attribute (use the custom attribute that needs to be imported.)

Yes, we can import it easily, SKU is mandatory and other, you can use a custom attribute that needs to be imported.

*NOTE: In M2, use the google spreadsheet product CSV to import the Products.*

thanks!

Nithin Ninan
nithincninan@gmail.com
9895382293

Comment: But product name and price etc is required field for product.what you do for this ? can you describe more.

Comment: @FeedlayTechnologies I have changed the title of this page. Can you check now.